# add semicolon on the end of the first line in csv file -groovy

Tags: csv, groovy

I would like to ask how can i add " ; " at the end of the first line of the following csv file:

file looks like this:

```
> field1,field2,field3,fieldN(here i would like to have a static semicolon [;]) 
> value1,value2,value3,valueN N rows....
```

so the payload at the end looks like:

```
 > field1,field2,field3,fieldN;
 > value1,value2,value3,valueN
```

Simple groovy code i tried (but it adds semicolon at the end of the file not at the end of the first line):

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;

def Message processData(Message message) {

//get payload and def string to append
        
    Map headerMap = message.getHeaders();
    def payload = message.getBody(java.lang.String);
    def a = ";";
    
 
 //append character and set as payload
    payload = payload + a;
    message.setBody(payload);
    
 //return   
    
 return message;
 }
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: you can probably find first newline and replace with ;  in the string.   Or you can iterate over lines , create new content based on what you really want - examples at @https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-working-with-lines-in.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already have the whole body loaded the impact of just
replacing the first line-break with your character (and a line-break)
should be a good compromise.  E.g.

```
def data = """a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i"""

assert data.replaceFirst("\n", ";\n") == "a,b,c;\nd,e,f\ng,h,i"
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: So could you show on above code how it would look like to add that one character (just a static value ;)?

Comment: @PawełGreen sorry, but it don't understand your question. Could you please provide an example for what you are asking? I am pretty sure, that this answers your original question though.

Comment: Hello again, what method should i use to add semicolon at the end of each line?

e.g.  > field1,field2,field3,fieldN;
 > value1,value2,value3,value4;
 > value1,value n;
etc.

Could you help me?

Comment: If `replaceFirst` replaces the first occurence, what function do you think would replace all occurences? Have you tried anything at all before you came here?

Comment: I used replaceAll at the beginning. I had to add semicolon at the end of the 1 line (with field names). Then i have been asked to add semicolon to every record in csv file. I found some workaround. I added additional field in CSV file like "toBeDeleted" and static value of "&" to all fields. Then used replaceAll from "&" to ";" and it works

Comment: Then why don't you just put the `;` in the last column instead of the `&`?

Comment: Thank you for asking, it is because our platform will not accept the name of the field as ';' It has to be text...limitations. But it is working thank you for help